# Pandas dataframe reorienting

Tags: python, pandas

```
        TA    Sector GP     OPR
ID              
AAPL    0.03   NaN   0.20   0.10
MSFT    0.04   NaN   0.30   0.05
AAPL    NaN    IT    NaN     NaN
MSFT    NaN    IT    NaN     NaN
```

I would like to convert the above frame into

```
Ticker Sector TA GO OPR
AAPL   IT      0.03 0.20 0.10
MSFT   IT      0.04 0.30 0.05
```

Is there a straight forward way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you concatenate two DataFrames to get this? If so, add an `axis=1` parameter to `pd.concat`.

Comment: Maybe, I am directly pulling this using an API where I specify the different fields needed . I believe what happens is, fields having similar frequency are returned in a single dataframe, the sector column is data at different frequency , and the API function just concatenates them together as you suggested

Comment: Do you have control over the API? Because this should be changed there...

Comment: In the meantime, will `df.groupby(level=0).first()` work?

Comment: Unfortunately cant control the API,but what you suggested does work. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be handled upstream if possible, but in the meantime the bandaid is using `groupby` on the index with `first`:

```
df.groupby(level=0).first()

        TA Sector   GP   OPR
ID                          
AAPL  0.03     IT  0.2  0.10
MSFT  0.04     IT  0.3  0.05
```